# Read date field from xlsx file via OleDb

Tags: date, oledb, xlsx

I have web service to parse `xlsx` files. It uses `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` provider and reads values from `xlsx` via `OleDbDataReader.GetValue()` method. And all works well on my local machine (`Win7 x64`) but on the server (`Win server 2003 SP2`) that service reads serial number of dates instead of text dates and it forces the service to throw an exception. I'm not to change service logic, only server properties. I have Excel and Access 2010 installed on both machines. Regional settings of windows are also the same. Please, help. What should I do to make my service always read text dates from date fields?

Comment: Please your Microsoft.ace. Drive and there dll version!!

Comment: I have ACEOLEDB.DLL ver. 14.0.6015.1000 on both machines